# High Disk I/O rate. How to investigate

Tags: hard-drive, io

One of my servers is getting very high Disk I/Os. The problem is that the disk I/Os are constantly increasing. The server just have simple LAMP configuration and there shouldnt be any disk operation ideally.

http://monitor.wingify.com/munin/visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/dev5.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com-iostat.html

Any help on how can I investigate as to what is causing this high disk I/O and how can I fix it. top / htop etc isnt giving me good information worth debugging

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) to find active I/O process.

Also, try remount xvda with noatime option and add "iostat -dx 2" output from host system.

Comment: Also anything special from `dmesg` might be useful, for example disk error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I second `iotop`, it's a great way to see what programmes are using your disk.